# jquery <li> click event to children elements

Tags: jquery, html, children

HTML

```
<ul id="wrapper">
    <li>
        <ul class="pr">
            <li>
                <ul class="pr">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>                       
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul class="pr">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>                       
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="etc">
            <li>
                <ul class="etc">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>                       
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul class="etc">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>                       
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want when click at each `li` elements, they adds a class to their children `ul` (closest `ul` only, not all `ul` inside them).

How to do that?

*Sorry for my bad English.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#wrapper li:has(ul)').click(function (e) {
    $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('myclass');
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9rUe5/)

Comment: thank you!
but i want they add class to closest children `ul` only, not all `ul` inside them.

Comment: the class is added only to that ul, but all the other elements are inheriting the property

Comment: @Boulevard see the update.. it was because of event propagation

Comment: use css to fix inheriting color `ul, ul.myclass li ul{
    color:black;
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li:has(ul)').click(function () {
    $(this).children('ul').addClass('ClassName');
});
```

References

[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

[:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

if you want to add class to all ul elements inside li use .`find()`

```
$('li:has(ul)').click(function () {
    $(this).find('ul').addClass('ClassName');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    // > mean one level children
    $('> ul', this).addClass('yourClass');
});
```